# Disable modal event processing in WINAPI

Tags: winapi, message-queue

As far as I understand, `WM_SIZING` is a modal message, meaning that the event processing will enter an inner loop and only return to the user when the resizing is over. I also know that this event begins with `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` and ends with `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

**My question is**: is there any way to disable this behavior so I can return to my own message loop after every single sizing event?

I know usually updates can be performed by setting a timer - and then killing it at the end of the modal message/event, but I'd like to return the control to my message loop.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You would have to run the sizing loop yourself (e.g. don't allow the mouseclick to go through to `DefWindowProc`). Seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm wrapping system APIs. The way I'm handling messages is I'm collecting them in a queue and then letting the user process them. Right now sizing freezes this queue.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ugh, do you mean having to implement the whole sizing behavior manually? That does sound pretty bad...

Comment: The system already queues messages for you. It sounds like you're trying to change the fundamental design of the OS. Good luck with that :)

Comment: Don't repeat Qt's mistakes. It does this and completely breaks native message handling. Things like `GetMessageTime` or `GetMessageExtraInfo` no longer produce the desired result. Lots of messages only give you a single chance to process them. Once you start batching them up, you've just blown your last chance.

Comment: @IInspectable How does Qt achieve this? Even if it's a bad idea, I'm very curious.

Comment: Qt is Open Source software. Make sure your curiosity is prepared to sift through functions with hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Do you want to use your own message queue instead of using `defwindowproc` to collect various messages? I feel a little weird.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I wanted to write an abstraction layer where the user could get an iterator to the messages and process them like that. But the modal loop basically takes away all control and becomes impossible to do this per-message.

Comment: All right.Other community members have given suggestions, which is an attempt to change the default behavior of the system. It seems to be troublesome.